# Need some guidance on how to sort/display MYSQL data on php page

Tags: php, mysql, vbulletin

I am looking to add some additional functionality to a memberlist. There are 2 files involved in this, and I need some guidance as to where this functionality should go.

File1) staff-members.php
File2) memberships.php

**staff-members.php** (a simple php page - that requires memberships.php to function)

```
<div>
<?php echo Memberships(91); ?>
</div>
```

As of right now (and as far as my knowledge goes), this page simply takes the array from the usergroup 91, and displays its contents on the screen.

---

**memberships.php** (This file has alot going on with it, as it is linked to vbulletin)
-I am going to try and post the snippets that I think are important to understand how the staff-members.php is populated. Let me know if you need something else

```
$Users = $vbulletin->db->query_read("
            SELECT user.userid, userfield.field31
            FROM " . TABLE_PREFIX . "user AS user
            LEFT JOIN " . TABLE_PREFIX . "userfield AS userfield ON(userfield.userid = user.userid)
            WHERE " . $Condition . " ORDER BY user.username ASC

            if ($vbulletin->userinfo['userid'])
            $Output .= '<span style="width:181px; text-align: left; display: block; float: left; font-weight: bold; color: #909090;">Username</span>';

        if ($vbulletin->userinfo['userid']) {

            $Output .= '<span style="width:62px; text-align: left; display: block; float: left; font-weight: bold; color: #909090;">Posts</span>';
            $Output .= '<span style="width:183px; text-align: left; display: block; float: left; font-weight: bold; color: #909090;">Steam Name</span>';
            $Output .= '<span style="width:100px; text-align: left; display: block; float: left; font-weight: bold; color: #909090;">Join Date</span>';
            $Output .= '<span style="width:81px; text-align: left; display: block; float: left; font-weight: bold; color: #909090;">Last Activity</span>';

        }
```

In the above code (again, as far as my knowledge) It takes the userid and username(field31) of a group and sorts them by their username.
Then it is added to $output with the formatting you see above?

---

Am I looking in the right places? The functionality I want is to have
Posts, Steam Name, Join Date, Last Activity clickable links on the staff-members.php page. as of right now, its only sorted by username, because of the ORDER BY in the SELECT statement. How would I go about adding this functionality? 
Thank You

Answer (score 0):

**IF** this functionality works as you have outlined the membership function will need an additional parameter added from something like

```
function membership(int $usergroup)
```

to something like

```
function membership(int $usergroup, $orderby, $direction)
```

inside the function will need some extra code added to parse the parameters like

```
switch($orderby)
{
    case 'posts' :
        $orderby = 'users.posts';
    break;

    case 'streamname' :
        $orderby = 'users.streamname';
    break;

    case 'lastactivity' :
        $orderby = 'users.lastactivity';
    break;

    case 'joinned' :
        $orderby = 'users.joinedate';
    break;

    default :
        $orderby = 'users.username';
}

switch ($direction) {
    case 'DESC' :
        $orderby .= ' DESC';
    break;

    default :
        $orderby .= ' ASC';
}
```

The field names depend on the database structure etc to the above is not exact

then just update the SQL order by to include `ORDER BY " . $orderby`

the final thing to do is get the ordering from the URL so update the staff-membership.php page with

```
<?php

$orderby = isset($_GET['order'])?:'username';
$direction = isset($_GET['sort']?:'asc';

echo membership(91, $orderby, $direction);

?>
```

then in the URL add the parameters so http://example.com/staff-membership.php becomes http://example.com/staff-membership.php?order=lastactivity&sort=DESC to let the list in latest activity first

***NOTE*** this is just a rough guide on how you might want to do this.